# OpenGL ES move object

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm writing an Android OpenGL ES 1.0 game. In this I want to move an object in the game with this method:

```
public void move(float dx, float dy, float dz)
{
    for(int i=0; i < objectVerts.length; i+=3)
    {
        objectVerts[i + 0] += dx;
        objectVerts[i + 1] += dy;
        objectVerts[i + 2] += dz;
    }
}
```

My render method looks like this:

```
gl.glViewport(0, 0, getViewportWidth(), getViewportHeight());
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
float aspectRatio = (float)activity.getViewportWidth() / activity.getViewportHeight();
GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 67, aspectRatio, 1, 100);

gl.glMatrixMode( GL10.GL_MODELVIEW );
gl.glLoadIdentity();
GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 1.5f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, objectVerts.length / 3);
```

But if I call the moves method the object does not move or change its position. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to re-upload the new vertices to the GL engine (using `glVertexPointer` and redraw using `glDrawArrays`). The `move` function runs on the CPU, and the GL engine has no way to know that the vertices have changed.